# Web API parameter is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have the following method in my Web API:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public bool MoveFile([FromBody] FileUserModel model)
{
    if (model.domain == "abc")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `FileUserModel` is defined as:

```
public class FileUserModel
{
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to call this through Fiddler but whenever I do the model is always set to null. In Fiddler I've sent the composer to use `POST`, the url is there and correct as the debugger in Visual Studio breaks when called. The Request I've setup as:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler 
Host: localhost:46992 
Content-Length: 127 
Content-Type: application/json
```

The Request Body as:

```
"{
  "domain": "dcas"
  "username": "sample string 2",
  "password": "sample string 3",
  "fileName": "sample string 4"
}"
```

But whenever I run the composer when the debugger hits the breakpoint it always shows model is null.

Comment: Does the request body have the surrounding double quotes as you've posted here?

Comment: is that a typo, that after domain: dcas there is no ","?

Comment: did you try to change input parameter type for one test from FileUserModel to string?

Comment: try solution as provided by me in below answer

Comment: @DavidG yes the request body starts and ends with the ", that's how I have it in Fiddler's Request body field.

Comment: @Mark good catch I will update and add it in

Comment: @PranayRana will try it, but wanted to see why it was not working in Fiddler as we are using that to run some tests

Comment: Then you need to remove those quotes, they are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is you are posting the JSON data with surrounding double quotes. Remove them and it should work.

Also fix the missing comma:

```
{
  "domain": "dcas",
  "username": "sample string 2",
  "password": "sample string 3",
  "fileName": "sample string 4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `,` in the request that you're sending. Also, because of the enclosing double quotes, you're actually sending a JSON string, not a JSON object. Removing the quotes and adding the comma should fix your problem.

```
{
    "domain": "dcas", // << here
    "username": "sample string 2",
    "password": "sample string 3",
    "fileName": "sample string 4"
}
```

Also, since you're posting a model, you don't need the `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public bool MoveFile(FileUserModel model)
{
    if (model.domain == "abc")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That should be just fine. For more information on this, see [this blog](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/).

Comment: It's redundant but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The edit is also incorrect, what is a "JSON string" in this context? With the quotes, the data is just meaningless to the API.

Comment: The edit does in fact give the correct answer. The request will be interpreted by the API as a JSON string, because the `Content-Type` (according to the OP's post) is  `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make ajax call like below

```
$(function () {
    var FileUserModel =    { domain: "dcas", username: "sample string 2", 
            password: "sample string 3", fileName: "sample string 4"};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data :JSON.stringify(FileUserModel ),
        url: "api/MoveFile",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});
```

Dont forget to mark content type as json and on server side api code

```
[HttpPost]
public bool MoveFile([FromBody] FileUserModel model)
{
    if (model.domain == "abc")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Sending HTML Form Data in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-1)

Comment: @DavidG - i correct that part in my code ...and also suggest some thing he need to check ...i think -1 is given when wrong solution is given, not for correct solution..is there any problem i suggest use of JSON.stringify and ask him to check  contentType: "application/json".. i guess nothing wrong in that

Comment: @DavidG - that doesnt mean to give -1 ...I am pointing all thing with jquery full code ...is there any harm in that ...if you happy with putting -1 no problem ..if you talk about wrong json that is updated in my answer...